# LibreOffice Calc hourly Y-axis with centered midnight (00:00)

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have a full year line chart that on the x-axis has the date (January to December) and on the y-axis the time (from 00 to 00 = 24), with noon in the middle (12:00). What I need is to have midnight in the middle (00:00). Is this possible? I have tried to modify the axis scale in various ways, but without success.

[image: Centered midnight needed]

Thank you!

---

Additional image:

[Additional image with more data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggUFe.png)

Comment: You want to shift the image 12 hours. Forward? Or back? You can try to add or to subtract 0.5 to dates (yes, to the X-axis, not the Y-axis). Don't worry about the ugly labels on the X-axis, you can format it so that this correction will not be visible.

Comment: Thank you @JohnSUN. Interesting approach. I tried adding and subtracting 0.5 days, but the y-axis is unchanged. I tried changes of a full day to test if the magnitude of change is as expected, and it is correct (0.5 = 12 hours) The chart is for display astronomical events, so I need midnight in the middle, instead of noon.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't write it very clearly (I reread it and realized that it could not be understood correctly). I meant "subtract or add half a day to dates and add or subtract the same number of hours from time." This means that the shift along the axes must be consistent (concordant, balanced). Can you place a sample graph with a large enough part of the data somewhere? (Please, not on OneDrive! Havn't MS account)

Comment: Aha! That did the trick. But the displayed data no longer has the objective meaning they need: sunrise is now in the afternoon, and the length of the night seems shortest in July, when in fact it should be the longest (data from the southern hemisphere). It is getting complicated to solve. I added a new image with sample data edited (added 0.5 days to data and hours)

Comment: Try [**Reverse direction**](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.1/en-US/text/schart/01/05040201.html).

Well, now we both know why on [**these charts**](https://www.timeanddate.com/sun/argentina/buenos-aires) it is midday in the middle and not midnight.

Comment: Thank you John! No luck. It seems like a conceptual limitation for a cases like this.